# Use of 'local' keyword in if statement

Tags: perl, cross-platform

I want to use this code :

```
if ($windows) {
    local $/ = "\r\n";
} else {
    local $/ = "\n";
}

# ... code reading a file line by line
```

But it doesn't work because local limits the scope to the enclosing brackets. What should i do ?

Is this the correct way ?

```
if ($windows) {
    $/ = "\r\n";
} else {
    $/ = "\n";
}

# ... code reading a file line by line
```

I'm scared it might have some side-effect on other programs..

Comment: You ***don't need to do this***. A WIndows build of Perl will use the `:crlf` PerlIO layer by default, and so your program will never have to deal with lines terminating in anything but a newline `"\n"` in either input or output. Just leave `$/` untouched (it is set to `"\n"` by default) and you will be fine. Setting it to `"\r\n"` will cause Perl read the entire file in one go as the sequence will never be found

Comment: You beat me to it - I was just looking this up.

Comment: He does if he uses `binmode`. But even then, he's probably better off looking for just LF and removing any preceding CR.

Comment: @Borodin, He's reading the file a line at a time if he's using `$/`.

Comment: For precision : the perl code is executed on a linux environment, and can read files produced by unix or windows systems.

Comment: So what does the `$windows` flag indicate?

Comment: @Borodin The user choose to launch it as windows or linux compliance with an optional argument.

Comment: @aurya: Okay thank you. I hope you will start including details like this in your questions, as your question misled several of us. In particular the cross-platform situation is very important and there is a tag for it which I have edited into your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have now explained that your `$windows` flag indicates whether the source of the file is a Windows platform

I would choose a whole different approach to this. You can either

```
my $fh;
if ( $windows ) {
    open $fh, '<:crlf', $filename;
}
else {
    open $fh, '<', $filename;
}
```

or, perhaps best, just open it normally

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename;
```

and then read it as

```
while ( <$fh> ) {
    s/\R\z//;
    # Process line
}
```

using `s/\R\z//` instead of `chomp` will remove the trailing line terminator regardless of its origin. Unfortunately `$/` isn't a regex pattern so `local $/ = qr/\R/` won't work

Comment: I like your second solution because it removes the need of an extra argument.

Comment: @aurya: Yes it does, as long as you always want to `chomp` each line of data. It's also worth pointing out that the `\R` construction has been available only since version 10 of Perl 5, so you should probably put a `use v5.10` at the top of your program and comment it to say why. Version 10 was released in December 2007 so only the most lax of installations will have anything less

Answer (score 6):

First way is to use the conditional operator:

```
{   local $/ = $windows ? "\r\n" : "\n";
    ...
}
```

The other way you could do it is this:

```
{ # enclosing scope
    local $/ = "\n";
    if ( $windows ) { $/ = "\r\n"; }
    ...
}
```

Or, you can just `local` it first and *then* assign it:

```
{   local $/;
    if ( $windows ) { 
       $/ = "\r\n";
    }
    else { 
        $/ = "\n";
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Whilst true in the general case - in this instance isn't necessary. `perl` already knows the difference between Windows and Unix line endings.

Comment: Except that the whole idea is unnecessary, and any of these solutions will confuse things dreadfully

Comment: @Borodin, is it *really* unnecessary? Suppose `$windows` only indicates the *intended* platform, not the current.

Comment: @Axeman: We can suppose a lot of things, including the use of `binmode` as ikegami has said, but that is a highly random assumption and you should include it in your answer if that is what you think

Comment: @Axeman exactly, the target platform is linux, but files comes from either windows or linux platform

Comment: @borodin, your comment, not mine, is closer to an absolute, the absolute claim *assumes* a context, not the counter case which invalidates the absolute. "Some A are B" refutes the case that "No A are B".

Comment: @aurya, Good, glad I could help. But there probably is a cross-platform modules you could use from CPAN, though. Your title asks a general question, your example is a specific example. "You don't need to do this" solves the specific application, but knowing you don't need to do that *here*, doesn't solve the *general* case illustrated that comes from a lack of familiarity with localizing variables.